# Immutables don't generate code with java 9 with modules

Tags: java, maven, java-9, java-platform-module-system, immutables-library

Using [immutables-library](https://immutables.github.io/) works fine with java 9 until I add a `module-info.java` to the project, `Immutables*.java` will no longer be generated.

To the module-info I add 'requires value' as suggested by IntelliJ.

What am I missing, is it a `immutables-library` issue or something else I need to set up in order for `javac` to find the annotation processing.

I am using maven with the `maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0`configured for ***target/source = 9***.

Comment: Could you share a sample of the project you're working on. What kind of errors in log if any you see during build etc?

Comment: Sure https://github.com/LarsKrogJensen/jigsaw-immutables

Comment: There are no errors during compile, but it does not generate any ImmutableSome.java as it does if I remove the modules-info.java

Comment: That seems like a lib issue, could you try executing `mvn clean install -X` (debug mode) to see if there's any lead there. Also
*works fine with java 9 until I add a module-info.java* seems to be an incorrect assumption, since I believe you might be ending up compiling the code without modules in that case.

Comment: @LarsKJ You should add supplemental executions in a pom based on the usage of JDK 9...only defined the version of the maven-compiler-plugin...best is define only the version of the plugin via pluginManagement nothing more. I've got the feeling that this is your problem ..I'm not sure how and when the ImmutableSome.java class will be generated...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem you have is that you haven't configured the Immutable part as a annotation processor which should be done like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jigsaw</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
            <artifactId>value</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>9</source>
            <target>9</target>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
                  <artifactId>value</artifactId>
                  <version>2.5.6</version>
              </dependency>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Apart from hints about encoding which simply can be fixed by defining the encoding like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jigsaw</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
            <artifactId>value</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>9</source>
            <target>9</target>
            <annotationProcessorPaths>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
                  <artifactId>value</artifactId>
                  <version>2.5.6</version>
              </dependency>
            </annotationProcessorPaths>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If you build via the above configuration you will get all the things you need:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       └── java
│           ├── example
│           │   └── Some.java
│           └── module-info.java
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   ├── example
    │   │   ├── ImmutableSome$1.class
    │   │   ├── ImmutableSome$Builder.class
    │   │   ├── ImmutableSome.class
    │   │   └── Some.class
    │   └── module-info.class
    ├── generated-sources
    │   └── annotations
    │       └── example
    │           └── ImmutableSome.java
    ├── jigsaw-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ├── maven-archiver
    │   └── pom.properties
    └── maven-status
        └── maven-compiler-plugin
            └── compile
                └── default-compile
                    ├── createdFiles.lst
                    └── inputFiles.lst
```

Comment: Thanx a alot - now maven generates the source. Though I have never had to tell maven in this way - it has always picked it up the annotation processor from the classpath. I guess this will be improved.
A minor issue is that Intellij does not pick up this configuration.

Comment: If you are running with JDK 9 it might be a different story.But I'm not sure about...

Comment: I have rechecked this. And you are right. There is a behaviour change between JDK 8 and JDK 9 ...Filed in an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-310).